# Iterate through rows and for each one send an email using the email on the last column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains multiple columns with financial and personal information of customers and advisors. Each customer has a Financial Advisor whose email is located in the last column.

First problem I am facing is that **various customers have one Financial Advisor in common so I would need a for loop to group all the customers in one email for the respective Financial Advisor**.

Also, I want to **select only a few columns to send the information and then send it through to the Financial Advisor's email as a table**.

To illustrate:

```
d = {'Name': [John, Sheila, Bryan], 'Product': [Treasury Bond, Treasury Bond, Treasury Bond], 'Quantity': [10,20,30] , 'Financial Advisor's Name':[ Jack, Jack, Claudia], 'Financial Advisor's Email': [jack@gmail.com,jack@gmail.com,claudia@gmail.com]}


    def create_message(send_from, send_to,subject, plain_text_body):
        sender_address = "sender@email.com"
        mail_content="This is a test message"
        for a, b, c, in zip(d['Name'], d['Product'], d['Financial Advisor's Name'], d['Quantity']):
            if 

            message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            message['From'] = send_from
            message['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
            message['Cc'] = cc_to
            message['Subject'] = subject
            message.attach(MIMEText(plain_text_body, 'plain'))
            return message
```

How do I assign the emails I have on the last column to the sender_address variable ? And how to use an If statement to send just one email to the Financial Advisor with his various customers ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
# dummy function mimic send email function
def send_email(advisor_name, data):
    print('email to '+advisor_name)
    print(data)

# group the dataframe by Financial Advisor\'s Name
grouped = df.groupby(['Financial Advisor\'s Name'])


for advisor_name, group in grouped:
    # suppose we want to send the column Name and Product
    # advisor_name will give you the name of the advisor
    # group is the corresponding group
    send_email(advisor_name, group.loc[:,['Name', 'Product']])
```

Comment: Thanks Epsi95, I want to highlight that I cannot specify each advisor's name as this dataframe has more than 50 thousand rows ( Advisors). Also, I was wondering if you could explain I little bit more what each line of code does.

Comment: @AlexandrePazoliniDibbe added the comments

Comment: Appreciate the comments @Epsi95, any chance you could explain some more about advisor_name and data ? How will I integrate this code into what I have here ? The send email function as you posted by itself doesnt do much right ?

Comment: yes, it is dummy function. But you can seeit has `advisor_name` and `data`. You can use these 2 variables to send customized email.

Comment: You can print this 2 variables at your side to check the output.